# Is there an example of someone trying to incite violence being found innocent because the speech was too ineffectual to pass the Brandenburg test?

Tags: united-states, freedom-of-speech

As I understand it the Brandenburg test for deciding if speech is protected has two parts:

1. The speech is “directed to inciting or producing imminent lawless action,” AND
2. The speech is “likely to incite or produce such action.”

I've seen plenty of cases dealing with #1, I'm curious of #2.  Is there precedent of a case where someone was doing their best to incite imminent lawless action to a crowed of people but got away without punishment due to an argument that they were too ineffectual in their persuasion to expect it was likely anyone would actually engage in action they were campaigning for,?